# Google search type tooltip

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy the Google search tooltip that appears on mouse over the search input box. For some reason, however, when I inspect the element using Google Chrome Developer Tools, and look at the event bound to the input box, I can't see any `mouseover`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's done using the `title` HTML attribute:

```
<input title="Search" ... />
```